# Modify multidimensional array of symbols

Tags: arrays, ruby

At the moment I have something like:

```
arr = [
  :name,
  :address,
  cards_attributes: [
    :last_name,
    :first_name,
    phones_attributes: [
      :number,
      :_destroy
    ],
    emails_attributes: [
      :number,
      :_destroy
    ],
    ...
  ]
]
```

... and I want to turn it into something like:

```
arr = [
  :id, # <- new!
  :name,
  :address,
  cards_attributes: [
    :id, # <- new!
    :last_name,
    :first_name,
    phones_attributes: [
      :id, # <- new!
      :number,
      :_destroy
    ],
    emails_attributes: [
      :id, # <- new!
      :number,
      :_destroy
    ],
    ...
  ]
]
```

I know I can add a new symbol to the first level with `arr.push(:id)` but how do I add elements into the sub hashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def add_id(collection)
  collection.unshift(:id) if collection.respond_to?(:unshift)

  collection.each do |key, value|
    add_id(key)   if key.respond_to?(:each)
    add_id(value) if value.respond_to?(:each)
  end
end
```

---

**EDIT**: For the following update

> *"My question was actually more about how to elegantly access the sub hashes?"*

We can use the same general idea. As you didn't specify an operation to be executed on the hashes, the method will expect a block:

```
def traverse(collection)
  yield collection if collection.is_a? Hash

  collection.each do |key, value|
    traverse(key)   if key.respond_to?(:each)
    traverse(value) if value.respond_to?(:each)
  end
end

traverse(arr) { |hash| puts hash }
```

Comment: Thanks, clever. My question was actually more about how to elegantly access the sub hashes?

Comment: @kitsched, ruby 2.3.0+ `#dig`, ruby 2.3.0 - + rails => `#try`.

Answer (score 1):

**This was an answer to the original question before the edit**

```
arr.unshift(:id)
arr[-1][:cards_attributes].unshift(:id)
arr[-1][:cards_attributes][-1][:phones_attributes].unshift(:id)
```

or if you don't like using indices,

```
arr.unshift(:id)
arr.last[:cards_attributes].unshift(:id)
arr.last[:cards_attributes].last[:phones_attributes].unshift(:id)
```

or, you can also do:

```
arr.unshift(:id)
arr.dig(-1, :cards_attributes).unshift(:id)
arr.dig(-1, :cards_attributes, -1, :phones_attributes).unshift(:id)
```

Comment: So you have to know the numerical indices. I was hoping for some clever shorcut to access by the symbol.

Comment: The index will always be `-1` as that is the only position within an array where you can omit the braces around the hashes.

Comment: Just to mess with you I have edited my question. :) (i have added `emails_attributes`)

Comment: kitsched, I considered, "Just to mess with you I downvoted your question for changing it, particularly because you didn't say you had done so" (but thought better of it). Changing the question after comments or questions have been posted is a no-no. It can render those postings puzzling or nonsensical; it  might even generate undeserved downvotes.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, duly noted. But that was a joke because I saw sawa edited the answer a few times and after it reached its final form I added the comment. I haven't changed the question in any fundamental way as to make the answers irrelevant. Anyway, lesson learned.